# Many Docker Containers and Thrift

Tags: docker, docker-compose, symlink, thrift

I have a Thrift file that I want many different containers to use. I need this file to be "compiled" (for lack of a better word) by Thrift in these several containers at Docker build time.

I tried putting the Thrift code in a parent directory and symlinking to it, but Docker does not follow symlinks to parent directories for security. Due to the need to compile this code at build time, volumes seems to not work.

Any ideas of how to solve my problem?

EDIT:

My current directory structure looks like

```
./docker-compose.yaml
./data-management/cassandra/Dockerfile
./data-management/tomcat/Dockerfile
./data-management/lmdb/Dockerfile
```

Each of those individual containers needs to use a common thrift file.

Comment: are you using docker-compose or/and have a Dockerfile ?

Comment: Just edited my question for more detail. But yes, I am using both compose and Dockerfiles